# Why does XCode ignore file write protection?

Tags: xcode, version-control, xcode5

I've just upgraded to XCode 5.  Now, as soon as I type into the code editor showing a project's read-only file (accidentally or misguidedly) XCode makes it writable.  No warning.  No visual indication at all.  I don't even have to attempt to save it.

We do use source control, but not git or subversion.

As you can imagine this is quite disastrous.  I have tried with "source control" enabled and disabled, with no change in behaviour.  I've tried searching on the web as well as here, but haven't even found a reference to this behaviour, let alone any complaint.  Is it just me?

Is there a way to turn it off?

Thanks.

Comment: Let me guess, Perforce? If so, set Perforce so that it doesn't set or check the readonly flag. It's only a convenience to tell people that they haven't checked out a file, but from a workflow perspective it causes more annoyances and disasters attempting to "fix perforce issues" when it detects a file that was accidentally set to writable without it being checked out. Perforce works just fine without the readonly flag.

Comment: Yes indeed, Perforce.  Thanks for your suggestion.  We could do this, and may have to do something like it (or use different tools), although pfaffing around checking for changed files and adding them to the change is manual, error-prone work.  It does only take 15-20 seconds to check which of the 9,000 files in this project have been edited.  Other products have hundreds of thousands.  I'm surprised you say a readonly flag is just a convenience - it's there as protection, and we do have source that mustn't be edited.

Comment: It's a "you didn't checkout the file" reminder more than a convenience or protection. All the other versioning tools do without it. OTOH except for this aspect Perforce rocks everyone else's boat.